# ssh-agent: How to keep the login key, and add more identities?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

When I log in to my local Ubuntu 14 instance from Windows (I use [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/) as a SSH client) using my RSA key, the key is available for forwarding for further SSH sessions (it is listed with `ssh-add -l`). However, I can't add more identities to the default agent:

```
# ssh-add -l
2047 29:c7:24:ca:ee:21:c8:1c:8e:31:7b:60:d9:45:45:df "rsa-vwal-20160112" (RSA)
# ps aux | grep ssh-agent
ville      3102  0.0  0.1  12968  2280 pts/3    S+   02:13   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
# env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.50.101 30920 22
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.50.101 30920 192.168.220.20 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-UVKqhSow2l/agent.2679
# ssh-add /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey
Enter passphrase for /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey: 
SSH_AGENT_FAILURE
Could not add identity: /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey
#
```

I assume this is because there is no real `ssh-agent` process; apparently the initial agent is provided by `sshd`(?)

Now if I start a new agent and apply the environment variables it generates so that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` changes, I can add identities to the agent...

```
# ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-G8dg8bePFC8K/agent.3115; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=3116; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3116;
# SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-G8dg8bePFC8K/agent.3115; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
# SSH_AGENT_PID=3116; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
# ps aux | grep ssh-agent                  
ville      3116  0.0  0.0  10628   320 ?        Ss   02:16   0:00 ssh-agent
ville      3128  0.0  0.1  12968  2120 pts/3    S+   02:20   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
# ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
# ssh-add /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey
Enter passphrase for /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey: 
Identity added: /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey (/home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey)
# ssh-add -l                                 
2048 05:9c:bc:b5:cd:e4:4e:a1:53:60:57:b4:39:e4:18:d5 /home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey (RSA)
#
```

... but obviously the initial key is no longer available because the agent is now different.

My question is: **Is it possible to retain the login key in the agent, AND be able to add more identities to it with `ssh-add`?** Can I, for example, make the initial agent accept additional identities to it, or perhaps somehow duplicate the login key into the explicitly instantiated agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem of `ssh-agent`, but of your Windows client (providing `ssh-agent` interface). It looks like it does not implement interface to add another key from the socket. This should not be a problem with normal `ssh-agent`.

Only possible solution today, I know about is to copy the key to your local host.

There is open [upstream openssh bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/attachment.cgi?id=2730) (client changes) requesting similar functionality (support for the list of agents), which should solve your issue.

Comment: Ah, I see.. the reason for why I'm not seeing the ssh-agent process at first is that the Ubuntu SSH_AUTH_SOCK is providing a socket to the agent in SecureCRT.

Thanks for the explanation; I'm opening a feature request on SecureCRT side based on this answer.

Comment: For those interested, the associated SecureCRT feature request is now open here ->> http://fetch.link/1Z3sBkC

Comment: This is another related SecureCRT feature request ->> http://fetch.link/2jxALr3